# Transform output of the pairwise.wilcox.test test into a list

Tags: r, list

I want to transform the output matrix from the pairwise.wilcox.test:

```
> df <- data.frame(obs = c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 10), rep("c", 10), rep("d", 10)), 

                   vars = c(runif(10, 1, 3), runif(10, 1, 6), runif(10, 3, 7), runif(10, 2, 9)))

> pairwise.wilcox.test(df$vars, df$obs)$p.value
             a          b         c
b 6.299985e-01         NA        NA
c 6.495053e-05 0.02052437        NA
d 6.495053e-05 0.01554483 0.6299985
```

into a list such as:

```
a  b  6.299985e-01
a  c  6.495053e-05
a  d  6.495053e-05
b  c  0.02052437
b  d  0.01554483
c  d  0.6299985
```

Is there any easy way of doing that?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
temp <-pairwise.wilcox.test(df$vars, df$obs)$p.value
df <- data.frame(expand.grid(dimnames(temp)),array(temp))
na.omit(df)
```

Comment: wooohoo, pretty cool :-). Is it somehow possible to swap the columns Var1 and Var2 so that Var2 comes before Var1? I tried using expand.grid(dimnames(temp)[1], dim names(temp)[2]). An easy way would be to just use subset() function to reorder the columns. However, I thought there might be a cooler way of doing it?

Comment: You can do it this way : `df[,c(1,2)] <- df[,c(2,1)]`